# Why is a date value jumping back 1 day on every PUT?

Tags: java, json, postgresql, rest, date

*Problem*

On every REST update, a date gets stored one day before the given date.

*Symptoms*

When I PUT `{'start': '2016-05-25', ...}` and then GET I get `{'start': '2016-05-24', ...}`.

When I PUT `{'start': '2016-02-12', ...}` and then GET I get `{'start': '2016-02-11', ...}`.

It should return the same date of course.

*The application*

I have a Java Spring Rest Controller that receives JSON data.

- method = PUT
- endpoint = '/term'
- body data = {'start': '2016-05-25', ...}

This object is represented in a DTO class:

```
public class TermDTO {

    @JsonProperty("start")
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd", timezone="Europe/Amsterdam")
    private Date startDate;

}
```

Then this DTO object is mapped to a Entity object somewhere:

```
public class TermEntity {

    @Column(name="start_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date startDate;

}
```

mapping:

```
public TermEntity map(TermDTO termDto){
    ...
    termEntity.setStartDate(termDto.getStartDate());
    ...
    return termEntity;
}
```

Later it is saved to a PostGreSQL database with this defnition:

```
-- term table
CREATE TABLE term (
  ...
  start_date         DATE,
  ...
);
```

Now, the perculiar thing is that this behaviour only happens on the server, and not on my local development environment.
This is probably caused by a different timezone on that server (UTC instead of Europe/Amsterdam).
I expect this has something to do with timezones. Maybe I need to explicitly define the timezone somewhere along the way.
Or should I used other java date types?
I would really like to fix it in the application instead of on the server (setting its timezone).

This seems hard to debug because it doesn't happen on my machine.
I hope you have a suggestion.

Comment: the `Date` class is `java.util.Date`

Comment: postgre DATE data type has no timezone. it uses TIMESTAMP data type to store time related info, including timezone. perhaps you can change the type of the column in the database and examine the values on local and server installations